Uniqueness of phase in Hamilton-Jacobi equation analogue
This question is about mathematics, but it came up in a very physical setting. When studying Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics, problem 2.38 asks us the following:

Show how one may obtain the correct wave function for a plane wave by starting with the solution of the classical Hamilton–Jacobi equation with $V(x)$ set equal to zero. Why do we get the exact wave function in this particular case?

We assume the wave function is proportional to $\exp\left[i S(x,t)/ \hbar\right]$, where $S(x,t)$ is a phase whose spatial derivative can be identified with momentum. The Hamilton-Jacobi equation in this case is
$$ H\left(x, \frac{\partial S}{\partial x}, t\right) + \frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2m}\left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \right)^{2} + \frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = 0. $$
The standard solution of this differential equation is obtained by letting $S(x,t) = X(x) + T(t)$, which then gives
$$ S(x,t) = \pm \sqrt{2 m \alpha}x - \alpha t, \tag{1}$$
where $\alpha > 0$ is some parameter, recovering the plane wave solution as
$$ \psi(x, t) \propto \exp\left[ \pm \frac{i}{\hbar} \left(\sqrt{2 m \alpha} x - \alpha t \right)\right]. $$
However, my first attempt was the ansatz $S(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, which also yielded a solution
$$ S(x,t) = \frac{\left( \sqrt{m\alpha / 2} \, x + c_1\right)^2}{\alpha t + c_2}, \tag{2}$$
corresponding to
$$ \psi(x,t) \propto \exp\left[ \frac{i \left( \sqrt{m\alpha / 2} \, x + c_1\right)^2}{\hbar\left(\alpha t + c_2\right) } \right]. $$
The two solutions above are completely different (I observed that my solution looks very similar to the free particle propagator, but that may just be a happy coincidence). How is it possible that the same Hamilton-Jacobi equation gave two different solutions? Is there any uniqueness theorem for nonlinear differential equations?
Also, what is the interpretation of the alternate solution I got, since it does not correspond to a plane wave?

OP's 1D free particle example is explained in my Phys.SE answer here.

@Qmechanic according to your wonderful answer, the expected solution is Hamilton's principal function, which is a function of $x$, $\alpha$, and $t$; while my ansatz is what's called the "on-shell action", and is a function of boundary values, meaning I cannot differentiate it with respect to $x$ and $t$. Is my understanding correct? Which of my assumption is wrong that led me to the wrong solution?

Differential equations can generally be solved in different ways by, for example, picking different coordinate systems. The Helmholtz equation, for example, produce plane waves for the Cartesian coordinates and Bessel modes in cylindrical coordinates.


Hamilton's principal function [of which OP's solution (1) is an example] is usually taken to be a complete solution [but not necessarily a general solution!] to the HJ equation, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer here.

OP's solution (2) is an example of an on-shell action $S(q_f;t_f;q_i,t_i)$ as explained in my Phys.SE answer here.

The on-shell action $S(q_f;t_f;q_i,t_i)$ is the leading contribution to the WKB expansion of the propagator
$$ \ln\langle q_f;t_f|q_i,t_i \rangle~=~\frac{i}{\hbar}S(q_f;t_f;q_i,t_i)+{\cal O}(\hbar^0) $$
for $\hbar\to 0$.



What is the physical interpretation (if there is one!) of the on-shell action as you mentioned? And to bring up my original question/conjecture: does this have anything to do with the corresponding propagator?

I updated the answer.
